# Polkit uses 100% CPU on a hardened Gentoo Linux profile?

Tags: linux, gentoo, polkit

I've just recently noticed that `polkitd` uses 100% of the CPU on a hardened Gentoo Linux profile. I use Gentoo Linux (testing), and have recently switched to a hardened profile. I tested this issue with a non-hardened kernel (4.7.2) and I found no problems with the CPU usage.

[Here is a paste of my system information](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/exHERQtS3YN70JAeS8Yp/), as well as a [link to my kernel protection information](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/GFjOAxQ7esWFgpkachAt/).

The following image shows `top` while `polkitd` is running:
[image: Top with polkitd running]

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: There could be thousands of reasons for this.  Looking at your system's logs would usually indicate where the problem comes from.  Your mention on the use a hardened vs not hardened kernel is not very clear to me.  If both kernels don't include the same options, it could make a huge difference and you need to pinpoint the differences to move on, if the logs didn't already answer you.

Comment: the problem occurs only with the hardened kernel, I do not want the problem was "jit" but I would not know " jit  Enable just-in-time compilation for improved performance. May prevent use of some PaX memory protection features in Gentoo Hardened. "